# How to use CPLEX timelimit in my code?

Tags: c, linux, cplex, time-limiting

I am using C to write my code and solve it with CPLEX optimizer. I want to limit the time on CPLEX so that it stops solving if time is larger than 10 hours. 
I have search online and I found the timelimit parameter of CPLEX. However, I do not know where to insert it or how to use it.
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter for time limit in the C interface is [CPX_PARAM_TILIM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/topic/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX1072.html).  It is a double parameters, and the value represents the number of seconds cplex will run before returning the best solution it has so far (unless it finds an optimal solution earlier).  You set the parameter with the [CPXsetdblparam](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/html/functions/CPXsetdblparam.html) function.  To set a time limit of 10 hours, you would call

```
CPXsetdblparam(env, CPX_PARAM_TILIM, 36000.0);
```

By default, cplex uses wall clock time, but if you want 10 hours of CPU time, you can set the integer parameter CPX_PARAM_CLOCKTYPE to value 1.

Answer (score 1):

As of CPLEX version 12.9, `IloCplex::TiLim` is [deprecated](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.DoubleParam.html#TiLim). Use `IloCplex::Param::TimeLimit` instead:

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::TimeLimit, 7200);
```

Answer (score 0):

In cplex(12.7.1 version) c++ interface, I use the following code:

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::TiLim, 1);
```

so cplex has limit running time: 1s.